# How to query results that don't contain the #N/A error in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

I am trying to query results that don't contain `#N/A` results from another sheet in the same Google Sheets WorkSheet.

I have tried this formula but it won't work

```
=QUERY('Table 1'!A2:G500, "Select F Where G <> '#N/A'")
```

Tried several other ways but still in vain.

I need to select Column F where column G does not contain #N/A.

Please help if you might know how to go about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try like this:

```
=QUERY('Table 1'!A2:G500, "select F where not G contains '#N/A'", 0)
```

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR('Table 1'!A2:G500), "select Col6 where Col7 is not null", 0))
```